# First-order logic sentences that consist of 2 clauses

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

When predicates are given as the following,

```
Programmer(x)               x is a programmer
can_programming(x)          x is capable of programming
programming_language(x)     x is a programming language
more_difficult(x,y)         x is more difficult than y
can_use(x,y)                x can use y
```

and constants

```
Java            programming language Java
C               programming language C
```

and variable names are

```
x, y, z
```

, then I can express some simple sentences like

```
(a) All programmers are capable of programming

 ∀x can_programming(x)

(b) C is more difficult than any other language

∀x more_difficult(C, x)
```

, but when it comes to a little more complex sentences like

```
(c) In order to be able to write a program, you need to know at least one programming language
(d) Java is a programming language that all programmers can use, but there are also other programming languages besides Java
(e) Someone who can use Java can use all other programming languages, possibly excluding C
(f) Someone who can use a programming language that is more difficult than other languages, can use C
```

, I don't know how to combine the logic math symbols and predicates.

How do I do it?

Comment: This is a matter of translation: Example: "In order to be able to write a program, you need to know at least one programming language" can be rephrased as "for all $x$ if there exists $y$ where $y$ is a programming language and $x$ can use $y$, then $x$ is capable of programming".

Comment: Your translation of (a) is incorrect. $\forall x (capable\_programming(x))$ says "*Everyone* is capable of programming". Instead, you want to restrict yourself to the programmers: "For everyone it holds that if they are a programmer, then they are capable of programming." This tranlstes as $\forall x(programmer(x) \to capable\_programming(x)$. In general, "All P Q" translates as $\forall x (P(x) \to Q(x))$, and "Some P Q" translates as $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now I'm working on (f)  ∀x (∃y (programming_language(y) ∧ more_difficult(y, ???all the others???) ∧ can_use(x,y)) -> can_use(x, C)), but not really sure how to express "all the others" "anything other than" etc. In this, I'm trying to write "if you can use the programming language y that is more difficult than all other languages, then you can use C". How do I write "all others"?

Comment: Utilise a third entity, $z$.

Comment: Is putting three variables in front of parenthesis legitimate? I tried to utilise a third entity z, and it became like this... ∀x∃y∀z (programming_language(y) ∧ y ≠ z ∧ more_difficult(y, z) ∧ can_use(x,z)) -> can_use(x, C))

Answer (score 1):

> , then I can express some simple sentences like
>
> > (a) All programmers are capable of programming
>
> ∀x can_programming(x)

That says "Every *thing* is capable of programming."  You need to restrict the statement to be about programmers.

$\forall x~[\operatorname{Programmer}(x)\to \operatorname{can\_programming}(x)]$

> > (b) C is more difficult than any other language
>
> ∀x more_difficult(C, x)

Likewise you need to restrict the statement to be about programming languages, and further to other languages than C.

$\forall x~[(\operatorname{programming\_language}(x)\land x\neq C)\to\operatorname{more\_difficult}(C,x)]$

> In order to be able to write a program, you need to know at least one programming language.

First determine if this statement is specifically about "you", or about anyone?   Well, we'll assume it is general since we don't have a constant representing "you".

So "If anyone is capable of programming, then there exists a language that they can use." is

$$\forall y\exists x~[\operatorname{can\_programming}(y)\to(\operatorname{programming\_language}(x)\land\operatorname{can\_use}(y,x))]$$

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It's people in general, so I think "If anyone is..." suits better.